# django install error in cygwin, shows some permission denied

Tags: python, django, windows, pip

```
$ pip install django==1.8
```

-bash: /cygdrive/u/Django project/djangogirls/myvenv/bin/pip: "/cygdrive/u/Django: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Comment: @fattidare, suggesting sudo in a virtualenv makes little sense.

Comment: try to remove the space 'Django project' -> 'Django_project'